# How can i install wkhtmltopdf in docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, wkhtmltopdf, c#-7.0

I am curently trying to implement an application that will run in a docker container.

One of the features this application should have is to generate a image (png, jpg, ...) from a HTML file.

I already got this working on my desktop using CoreHtmlToImage using wkhtmltopdf.

Now the problem is that if i try running the application in a docker container it isn´t able to find wkhtmltopdf.

```
System.Exception: wkhtmltoimage does not appear to be installed on this linux system according to which command; go to https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
   at CoreHtmlToImage.HtmlConverter..cctor()
```

I tried to install wkhtmltopdf in the docker container through the Dockerfile but so far all attempts failed.